# Query for all roles with a given privilege grant in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any means of querying Snowflake for all the roles (and/or users) where a specific privilege has been granted? I know how to `show grants to <role>` but I'm not so sure of how to find the roles that have a grant.

This is not something that needs to happen regularly--i'm just looking for ways to better understand this instance and its usage.

Comment: Did you check this view GRANTS_TO_ROLES, may be this could help   https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/grants_to_roles.html#grants-to-roles-view

Comment: i haven't tried that, thanks. I'll see if that could generate the list I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Himanshu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11227919/himanshu-kandpal), I was able to work out a query that answers my question exactly:

```sql
select distinct(grantee_name) from snowflake.account_usage.grants_to_roles -- this system view is updated every ~120 minutes
where privilege = 'USAGE' -- name of the privilege
and granted_on = 'WAREHOUSE' -- not strictly necessary, but name of the type of object
and name = 'MY_SPECIFIC_WAREHOUSE'; -- the important constraint for my case
```